# Convert HTML form to Rails form : Helping out a total noob

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails I have an HTML form but I don't know how to keep the CSS classes. Just turning the form into rails.

```
<form action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="lx-contact-field">
        <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Jane Doe" />
    </div>
    <div class="lx-contact-field">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Jane@Doe.com" />
    </div>
    <div class="lx-contact-field">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message here ..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep CSS classes in your divs, and replace html input field with Rails textfield

```
<div class="lx-contact-field">
   <%= f.text_field :full_name, placeholder: "Jane Doe" %>
</div>
```